# Make plane move towards the direction its pointing towards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

plane always moves in the same direction even when rotating it physically(forward force always added on x axis even if its pointing z axis), how can i fix this

---

```
    if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) && EngineOn == true)
    {
        
        rb.AddForce(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.Acceleration);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
    {
        Thrust = false;
    }

    if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) && EngineOn == true)
    {
        rb.AddForce(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.Acceleration);
    }
    speed -= transform.forward.y * Time.deltaTime * 50;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        transform.Rotate(-transform.forward * rotSpeed1 * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) 
    {
        transform.Rotate(transform.forward * rotSpeed1 * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) ||  (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)))
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.left * rotSpeed1 * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) ||  (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))) 
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * rotSpeed1 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Comment: `rb.AddForce(transform.forward * speed, 0, 0, ForceMode.Acceleration)`. Remove the `* Time.deltaTime` as force is applied in a single frame then handled by the physics engine over time. All you are doing is making your scalar reduced by your average frame elapsed time, most likely `0.016666667` (1/60).

Answer (score 0):

`transform.forward` will always point to the place the GameObject is looking at. You can add force using that as a direction, or displace it by setting its position.

Examples:

`transform.Position = transform.Position + (transform.forward * Time.DeltaTime)`

or as TEEBQNE pointed out:

`rb.AddForce(transform.forward * speed, 0, 0, ForceMode.Acceleration). Remove the * Time.deltaTime`

Answer (score 0):

The `AddForce`[1] method is not relative to the transform, but the world axis. To get a transform's forwards vector in the world axis, use the `forward` property[2].

The `AddForce` method has two overloads, where you either pass a vector, or the individual vector components as separate arguments. In this case, using a vector will be cleaner.

As TEEBQNE already mentioned, when using `AddForce` with the `ForceMode.Acceleration` parameter, multiplying the acceleration by the time delta is not required, as the change in velocity of your rigidbody is handled by the physics engine (you can think of the `AddForce` method with `Acceleration` parameter as specifying what acceleration you'd like the body to have at the current frame).

Putting it all together, you can accelerate your rigidbody along it's Z (forward) axis like this:

```
rb.AddForce(transform.forward * speed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
```

You can transform any transform-local vector to world space by using `TransformDirection`.[4] That way you'd also be able to do sideways movement. To go backwards, just negate the `forward` vector.

Note that physics calculations (rigidbodies, etc.) are done on a separate fixed timestep. Since you're using a rigidbody, make sure your movement is being handled in `FixedUpdate`, not `Update`. The time delta is different between both, however `Time.deltaTime` returns the fixed delta if used within `FixedUpdate()`[3]. Still, I'd recommend explicitly using `Time.fixedDeltaTime` for clarity.

Additionally, manually adjusting transforms of physics objects (via `Translate`, `Rotate` and others) is discouraged, as it can lead to physics glitches.

1. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html
2. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html
3. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html
4. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformDirection.html